# What does の元で mean?

Tags: meaning, usage, nuances

> 彼**の元で**護衛を務める。

Does it mean "for", "on behalf of", "in the name of"? Or "under the guidance of"?

What's the difference between that and の下で?

Can I replace で with に?

Comment: 下/元/基 are often confused even by some native speakers...

Comment: It's official though. I've simplified the text, but you can see the original one: https://www.otomate.jp/kurenai/chara/?page=sasuke

Comment: Is it a mistake?

Comment: Yes I think it's a common mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is using a wrong kanji, strictly speaking.

- [元](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%9C%AC_%28%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%29/#jn-219563) refers to *source* like 怪我が元で仕事を辞めた
- [下](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%8B_%28%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%29/) means *under*. Could be written also as 許.

彼の下{もと}で護衛を務める could mean (1) *to work as a guard for him* or (2) *to work as a guard under him ("he" is also a guard)*. To me, 彼の下{した}で makes the interpretation (2) more likely.

Regarding the particle, here 務める means a state rather than a movement, so で is much more natural. 下に works better for action like 彼の下に集まる (gather around him as a leader). Also, a phrase like 法の下に平等である (equal under the law) is natural despite its being a state, but this kind of に should be only for written/strained expressions.

Comment: Is 下 read もと or した here? You've wrote both of them.

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Can be either, もと sounds more like (1) and した more like (2).